# Not compatible app and "install failed missing shared library"

Tags: installation, apk, emulators

I am currently trying to get a game app running in windows and got some problems. Ive already tested Bluestacks, SocketQ, Android x86, Youwave and the official Android SDK Emulator. Now I'm trying "Jar of Beans" from xda, which looks quite promising.

Anyway, I have the emulator running and the network works as well. The problem I have is that I cannot install the game app through the play store as it says, "my device isn't compatible". Android 4.1.1 is running and it has lots of RAM available (1GB I think) so I really don't know why it says it's not compatible. Is it possible to find that out somehow?

And when I try to install the apk via adb I get "install failed missing shared library".

Comment: You might have set the minimum and maximum api level in the manifests wrong. Are you the app developer? You might as well ask this in SO.

Comment: No I'm not the dev. But since I got the apk can't I look into the manifest and change something?
SO = StackOverflow?

Comment: I don't know much about changing manifests, just suggesting, and yes SO = StackOverflow. Library missing also might be caused by using NDK (Native Development Kit), since your running an x86 machine, native ARM codes are missing the necessary opcodes to run.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
I think it's not a matter of the emulator software you use, it's more probably a matter of which is the *emulated* device.

I don't recommend *Bluestacks*, because you may need the root rights (feasable on Bluestacks with hacks, but they are unstable). If you want an easy-to-install emulator with root rights, there's for instance Nox (Nox App player), MEMU and some other ones...

When you use the Google store, it detects which device you use, your screen configuration, and some other configuration details.

So there are several possibilities preventing you to install an app though the Google store:

1 - The detected screen resolution is not compatible

2 - The device is not compatible (not the right phone or tablet, works only on tablets, etc...)

3 - Some apps are impossible to run on an emulator (but it's the app that detects the emulator, not the store)

To solve problem 2, you have many tools to change the emulated device.
Depending on which emulator software you use, generally you find this option directly in the software options. You can choose another kind of phone with the name.

To solve problem 1, Trying to change the size of the window in which the app is emulated won't work, because the size of the window is not a parameter that is passed as a device parameter.
You have to change the configuration, not the size of the windows.

My favorite way is with hack app, often root rights, (you'll find many in the store, with words with "DPI" and "change" or "changer" in the name, but you have a way without rooting, it's for instance:

http://android.wonderhowto.com/how-to/change-your-androids-screen-resolution-without-root-access-0160439/

> Warning
>
> Keep in mind that altering your DPI may cause the Google Play Store to
>   incorrectly label your device as incompatible when downloading apps.
>   This is caused by developers limiting their app's compatibility based
>   on a device's DPI value. So if for any reason you get an error, all
>   you have to do is revert back to your original DPI and download the
>   app again. Once you have the app installed, you can switch back to
>   your custom DPI.
>
> Step 1
>
> Install ADB
>
> This whole process relies on issuing ADB commands to your device, so
>   if you don't have it installed on your computer, use one of the guides
>   linked below to grab a copy. And if you haven't already, enable USB
>   debugging from your Android's Developer options.
>
> ADB Installation Guide - Mac ADB Installation Guide - Windows Step
>   2Find Your Original DPI Before going any further, you should check
>   your original DPI in case you need to revert back later. Plug in your
>   Android to your computer, open up Terminal (Mac) or a Command Prompt
>   (Windows), then enter the following command (copy and paste works best
>   here):
>
> adb shell dumpsys display | grep mBaseDisplayInfo
>
> The output will have a part that says "density," next to which is your
>   original value. Write that number down somewhere safe.
>
> Step 3
>
> Change Your DPI The DPI you choose depends only on your personal
>   preference. Android devices ship with DPIs ranging from 120 up to 640,
>   but know that as you decrease the value, the icons and font size
>   decrease as well. Below you will find examples of various DPIs running
>   on an HTC One M8, so use those as a guide.
>
> (1) 200 DPI, (2) 400 DPI, (3) 600 DPI Now, in your Terminal or Command
>   Prompt window, enter the following command to change your DPI. (Make
>   sure to swap out DPI with whatever resolution you choose.)
>
> adb shell wm density DPI && adb reboot
>
> Your device will reboot automatically, and once back up, your new DPI
>   will be in effect.

I would try all that before trying to solve the ADB "Install failed missing shared library" problem.

If the other steps wouldn't work, you have solutions here to try for this error message: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375919/getting-error-msg-install-failed-missing-shared-library